how can i open the chrome browser using selenium
i need a basic code which opens the chrome browser, but the code isnt working
my chrome version is Version 123.0.6312.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
There is no chromedriver specific for my version, but there is a test chrome
i tried using both.
can someone guide me through this , iam a beginner to this selenium
from selenium import webdriver
chromepath = r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Automation\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')`

i tried the above but not working
showing error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')

but when i add the path as system variable the chrome is opening for a second and closing
showing error:The chromedriver version (114.0.5735.90) detected in PATH at C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Automation\chromedriver.exe might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (123.0.6312.106); currently, chromedriver 123.0.6312.105 is recommended for chrome 123.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry

Try this:
In the terminal:
pip install chromedriver_py

Script:
from selenium import webdriver
from chromedriver_py import binary_path
svc = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=binary_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
input("Press any key to exit.")
driver.quit()

